# Пользователи базы данных

Tags: delphi, interbase

Как программно подключиться к базе данных под любым из пользователей базы данных в приложении, созданном в Delphi? Какие компоненты используются для этого?

Answer (score 1):

Если `IBDatabase1` - это `ADOConnection` (или его аналог)

```
IBDatabase1.LoginPrompt:=true;
```